# Dynamic Bar Labeling on Ant Design Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, antd

I'm trying to create an ant design chart with some custom labels on the bars based on what data they contain. Is it possible to do this dynamically? I want the labels to say "Water" and "Land", which is the type of each respective data. Here is my code which I'm playing around in the [Ant Design Charts Sandbox](https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/bar/stacked#basic)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Bar } from '@ant-design/plots';

const DemoBar = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      year: '1991',
      value: 3,
      type: 'Water',
    },
    {
      year: '1991',
      value: 4,
      type: 'Land',
    },

  ];
  const config = {
    data: data.reverse(),
    isStack: true,
    xField: 'value',
    yField: 'year',
    seriesField: 'type',
    legend: false,
    label: {content: data[0].type}, // How can the content link to the data?
    interactions: [{ type: 'tooltip', enable: false }]
  };
  return <Bar {...config} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<DemoBar />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: Javascript lets you create a function here. Replacing the label line with this line solved it:
`label: {content: ({ type }) => { return type },},`

For typescript the line is:
`label: { content: ({ type }: any) => { return type }, },`

Answer (score 0):

It works when you add what attribute have in your data. Example: `xField` has **value** or `yField` has **year**

```
label: { content: ({ value or year}: any) => { return value or year}, },
```

[image: image here]

Comment: Please add a detailed explanation of how your answer solves the issue. To improve the quality of the answer and make it possible for most people to understand.